# Posting an image in full size using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook

I am posting a image with size 480*480 in facebook wall using php sdk. But, the posted image in wall gets resized to thumbnail. Is there a way to post an image to FB wall in the original size through PHP sdk api?

Appreciate your help on this.